# convert system date to M/d/yyyy format irrespective of system format using C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

How can I get today's date in `M/d/yyyy` format irrespective of system format of date using C#?

```
DateTime.Now.Tostring('M/d/yyyy')
```

is working only if the system date is in format `dd/MM/yyyy` or `M/dd/yyyy` but is not working in case `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Eg:

if system date is `2013-06-26` then `DateTime.Now.Tostring('M/d/yyyy')` is converting the date into `06-26-2013` but not in `06/26/2013`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you just need to use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) as a second parameter in your `.ToString` method.

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to enforce `/` as date separator:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

[**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/WXLhM1)

Answer (score 5):

Using the invariant culture is the correct solution if you always want the same DateTime to produce the exact same string on multiple systems (or even on the same system due to culture changes). However, be aware that if this is user-visible, you're giving up the possibility of internationalization (for instance, if you display day or month names, they will be in English regardless of what language the user speaks). To **only** ensure that slashes are not replaced with another date separator, use single quotation marks:

```
DateTime.Now.Tostring("M'/'d'/'yyyy");
```

---

#### Edit:

Also, if your users are using different date formats, there's a good chance they're also using different time zones. If this `DateTime` needs to make sense across multiple systems, consider using **[`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx)**. This will also protect you against potential bugs due to a user changing their time zone (when travelling, say) or daylight saving/summer time beginning/ending. If you're just displaying the string to the user at the current instance and not persisting it, `DateTime.Now` is probably what you want. In that case, however, I'd question why you're trying to mess with the format they've chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
DateTime.Now.Tostring("M'/'d'/'yyyy");
```

The apostrofe forces the `ToString()` method to use the delimiter that you specified.

However, I would let the user choose a culture and use that cultures default formatting instead.